# How to pass onclick event of HorizontalView to its prarent CardView

Tags: android, onclicklistener, horizontalscrollview, android-cardview

The CardView is added to my RecyclerView as a row item. When I click on any view inside CardView except HorizontalScrollView and its child views, the OnClickListener of CardView works fine. But, while clicking on HorizontalScrollView and the child views inside it, CardView's OnClickListener cannot be triggered.

cardview_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/license_plate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                tools:text="P3R-178" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vehicle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/scooter_selected"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/area_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView licensePlate;
        public TextView vehicle;
        public LinearLayout area;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            licensePlate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.license_plate);
            vehicle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle);
            area = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.area_container);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.w(Init.TAG, "licensePlate: " + licensePlate.getText().toString());
            Log.w(Init.TAG, "vehicle: " + vehicle.getText().toString());
        }

}
```